# Ejecutar archivo php con Cron de Cpanel para generar archivo y enviar Email

Tags: php, cpanel, cron

Estoy intentando crear un cron desde el Cpanel he intentado varios metodos

`wget -O - http://prueba.com/correo.php >/dev/null 2>&1`

`wget -q -O "http://www.sitiodeejemplo.com/ruta" >/dev/null 2>&1`

`/usr/bin/curl --user-agent cPanel-Cron "https://prueba.com/correo.php"`

`/usr/local/bin/ea-php72 /home/pecpanel/public_html/prueba.com/correo.php`

Con los 3 primeros no funciona, pero con el ultimo me arroja errores en el track delivery del Cpanel indicando:
`SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: 552 5.2.0 2euAlou0ne5Nz :: ded :: Message rejected for spam or virus content :: Please include this entire message when contacting support :`

Me pueden ayudar?

Comment: El mensaje del error creo que es descriptivo por si solo, el correo se clasifico como spam o virus. Modifica el contenido o busca las reglas para el envío de correos del servidor que va a recibir el correo

Comment: Si de hecho busque sobre ese error pero la realidad es otra, resulta que cuando el cron intentaba entrar al archivo adjunto no lo dejaba porque no tenia una session de usuario mandando como respuesta el inicio para ingresar al sistema

Comment: ¿? `cron` es sólo una herramienta para automatizar y programar tareas, no para el envío de correos electrónicos. Entendí que el servicio te retorna la página de login porque no configuraste la cookie para iniciar sesión. Lo más obvio sería pues setear la cookie, pero independientemente de eso, si lo que quieres es enviar un correo electrónico (protocolo `SMTP`), ¿por qué te regresó la página de login (protocolo `HTTP`)?

Comment: @BenjamínGuzmán Facil, en el archivo php simplemente le decia "Si no tiene sesion de usuario regresalo al login" por esta razon el cron no funcionaba correctamente como queria, pero en fin logre solucionarlo, el cron lo que realmente hace es visitar la pagina constamente que enviara el correo